# Why `binding.pry` halts at the wrong place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry-rails

For some reason when I set a breakpoint using `binding.pry`, the program ends up halting at a totally different (and alien looking!) place. Am I doing it wrong?

**Gemfile (shortended)**

```
gem "rails", "~> 4.1"
gem "pry"
gem "pry-rails"
gem "pry-doc"
gem "pry-stack_explorer"
gem "pry-byebug"
```

**Scenario**

*Break point:*

```ruby
class SomeController < Application controller
  before_filter :filter
  ...
  def filter
    assignment = SkillAssignment.where(day: selected_date).first

    if assignment
      @day_skill = assignment.skill
      @day_description = @day_skill.description
    end

    binding.pry
  end
end
```

*Where I land (using `show-source`):*

```ruby
[1] pry(ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::Before)> show-source

From: /home/yan-foto/workspaces/my-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb @ line 156:
Owner: #<Class:ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::Before>
Visibility: private
Number of lines: 16

def self.halting(next_callback, user_callback, halted_lambda, filter)
  lambda { |env|
    target = env.target
    value  = env.value
    halted = env.halted

    unless halted
      result = user_callback.call target, value
      env.halted = halted_lambda.call(target, result)
      if env.halted
        target.send :halted_callback_hook, filter
      end
    end
    next_callback.call env
  }
end
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about where you land? You can find this out by typing `whereami` or `@` in the Pry REPL.

Comment: @Manuel there you go!

Comment: Does it still happen if you move it above the magic?

Comment: @Manuel indeed! I added the magic part. It's simple ActiveRecord query. Why is this happening?

Comment: this is a bug in a 3rd party pry application called byebug.

Comment: @Anthony is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Manuel and @Anthony I know now that this problem is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/45) in [`pry-byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be fixed any soon as [mentioned by the developer in GitHub](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/45#issuecomment-68314470):

> The current situation is that I hardly ever use pry-byebug, so I feel
>   less motivated to mantain software I don't use. :(

If you want to have the `binding.pry` at the end line, a simple workaround would be to write something like this:

```
def myMethod
  # magic
  binding.pry
  1 + 1
end
```